# Receiving text messages multiple times

Tags: sms

**The problem is that I sometimes recieve bizarre text messages: two different kinds.**

*1st kind: I receive a text message multiple times after receiving it a first time. 

2nd kind: I receive a duplicate of a text message days after the real one was received.*

I have a Wiko Cink Slim Android device running 4.0.4.
It's a rather low power device (512 MB RAM, for example) but I get by fine with it.

I have tried a variety of SMS clients: stock, Hangouts, Textra, Hello... So far same problem.

I live in France and have a plan with a newer operator Free Mobile, which both piggybacks Orange's antennas and also has its own antennas. I have forced my phone onto Orange's antennas because I read online that sometimes the antenna switching could provoke problems like mine. So far no difference.

However, the problem occured especially when I turn on my Wifi or my Data connections. When I do this, many different applications run and it slows down the phone a lot. Then, I get multiple repeat text messages. 
I am leaning towards this hypothesis...

**Has anyone had a similar problem?**  
 **Anyone have a solution?**